# What is an interpretation of parts of statsmodels summary of Logistic Regression in Python?

Tags: python, logistic-regression, statsmodels, coefficients

I have results of Logistic Regression from statsmodels in Python like below:

[image]

My question is: What is interpretation of marked on yellow columns: `coef, std err, z, [0.025, 0.975]` ?

Comment: This is probably off-topic for StackOverflow. "*How do I interpret logistic regression metrics*" is more of a stats question than a programming question.

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/65636/how-to-interpret-statsmodel-output-logit